# How to position an element at a fixed position from the top until pushed by another element

Tags: html, css

I tried to find a question same as mine but I couldn't find one. Probably because I don't know the right words to explain my question.

Anyways, let's say I have a div that has dynamically generated content and below the div there is a button. I want to have some white space between the div and the button (about 200px). Here is a diagram to illustrate:

```
 ##############################
 #                            #
 #    Div with dynamically    #
 #     generated content      #
 #                            #
 ############################## 


           ↑
         200px
           ↓


       ##########
       # Button #
       ##########
```

However, if the div's height gets larger, I want the space between the div and button to collapse until a certain minimum distance. So basically the button should ***not*** move while the div gets larger and larger until a certain distance between the div and button (for example 5px).

I know questions should show some attempt to answer the question but I don't know where to start. I was thinking to absolutely position the button relative to the parent but then the div won't push it down. I know I should give the button a `margin-top:5px;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding another solution that satisfies my problem and it was so simple. I just have to wrap the expanding div with another div that has a `min-height`. So the expanding div will expand and not affect the position of the button until it goes past the `min-height` of its parent.

Nenad's answer was good as well but this one is more compatible cross-browser.

```css
.wrap {
 min-height:100px;
}
button {
 margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="inner">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
<button>Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this with `Flexbox` and `min-height` on `wrap` div and then you just add `margin-top` on `button`

So this is how it looks with short text

```css
.wrap {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">lorem</div>
  <button>BTN</button>
</div>
```

But when you increase text size `wrap` div increases its height but button still keep its `margin-top` distance to text.

```css
.wrap {
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem ut ducimus beatae veniam quam tenetur maxime, commodi quo, doloribus inventore amet blanditiis nihil voluptates voluptatum reprehenderit nam facilis assumenda consequuntur eius, qui dolorum id repudiandae.</div>
  <button>BTN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Nenad this looks great. What is the purpose of using `position:fixed`? It seems to work without it.

Comment: Your question is, and i quote `How to have an element that has a **fixed** position` `:)`

Comment: oh I see, that is why I said I don't know how to explain my question :). I just meant the button should be fixed until the div pushes it down.

Comment: You can remove `position: fixed` there is no need for it.

Comment: Do you know if there is a solution that will work for IE 8+?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery and use conditional statements to evaluate the distance between the elements. Something like:

```
var el1 = $("#firstElement").position();
var el2 = $("#secondElement").position();

if (el1.bottom > (el2.top+5)) {
    $("#secondElement).animate({ top: el2.bottom+5 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake this looks good so I +1ed it. I am looking for a non-javascript solution.